# Black formatter not installing on Windows laptop

Tags: python, automation, pip

[image]I am trying to install Black, the Python code formatter, on my Windows laptop using pip, it installed successfully, but when i am trying to use it, error is shown.

I have tried different versions of Python and also checked that my PATH variable is correctly set. However, the issue persists. Has anyone experienced a similar problem and found a solution? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this installation issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I have added the image and I am using VScode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are facing, means it must be an path based issue.

```
pip show black
```

to check the module is installed properly,

- Trying restarting the Code editor (Or check you are using right python interpreter)
- Trying adding path(Then restart the editor)

Verify the 'black' with following command:

```
black --version
```

You can also check the issue on github: [github Issue page](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/1558)

Thank You!